# Cannot explain why Alpine apk upgrade command does not update ncurses package although a newer version exists

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I have a Dockerfile as:

```
FROM nginx:1.21.3-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add bash \
    && apk upgrade
```

I can see that package `ncurses` is installed and the version is `6.2_p20210612-r0`.
Now, There is a newer package available in the `main` repository `edge` branch with version `6.2_p20211002-r0` [here](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/ncurses).

As far as I understand after building an image from the above mentioned Dockerfile the version of `ncurses` should be updated to `6.2_p20211002-r0` BUT instead it stays as `6.2_p20210612-r0`. I cannot understand why?

I confirmed this by running a container after build and running:

```sh
apk info -a ncurses
```

The output was:

```sh
ncurses-6.2_p20210612-r0 installed size:
284 KiB
```

Comment: `RUN apk update && apk upgrade` is not efficient. The correct command is `RUN apk upgrade --no-cache`. See stackoverflow.com/a/76440791/685806

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nginx:1.21.3-alpine` image is based on Alpine 3.14 (see `cat /etc/os-release`), and therefore ncurses is updated with the version of the Alpine 3.14 repository, which is currently [`6.2_p20210612-r0`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.14/main/x86_64/ncurses).

For installing `ncurses` from edge (currently version [`6.2_p20211002-r0`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/ncurses)), you could specify the edge repository explicitly in the `apk` command:

```
apk add ncurses --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
```

Mixing and matching packages from different repositories this way might be OK in some cases, but has to be tested carefully. For `ncurses`, some functionality might be broken, since the matching [`ncurses-libs`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/ncurses-libs) package should be installed as well, but some of the package images depend on `ncurses-libs`, so re-installing it triggers update of these packages. Moreover, the `nginx-module-njs` dependent package must be removed. If this is acceptable, you could modify the Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM nginx:1.21.3-alpine

RUN apk update && \
    apk del ncurses ncurses-libs nginx-module-njs && \
    apk add ncurses ncurses-libs --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main && \
    apk add bash && \
    apk upgrade
```